# VBA str(UBound(str)) Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Part of my macro splits a cell based on a "-", and it works fine, but it runs out of range and the macro stops. What can I do to avoid this error? This is not the last step of this macro, so I can't have it stop. The error occurs at `.Cells(K, 9).Value = str(UBound(str))`

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aluminum Futures")
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim K As Long
    For K = 2 To LR
        Dim str() As String
        str = Split(.Cells(K, 8), "-")
         .Cells(K, 9).Value = str(UBound(str))
    Next K
End With
```

Comment: Note: avoid using `str` as a variable since that shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Comment: What is the value of `.Cells(K, 8)` when this errors?

Comment: Probably use something like `If InStr(.Cells(K, 8).Value, "-") > 0 Then` before attempting to `Split`.

Comment: If the cell is empty, you'd get that error since the array returned by `split` will have a `ubound` of -1

Comment: @Rory how can I mitigate this error

Comment: Test for the empty cell first: `If len(.Cells(K, 8).value) <> 0 then` or test `If Ubound(str) > -1 then`